# 'Schau sie dir doch an'

Tags: grammar, german-to-english

I'm trying to understand the following phrase (the bit in bold is the bit I don't get - the rest is fine):

> **Schau sie dir doch an**, wie sie aussehen, die für ein bißchen Wohlstand ihr Leben und ihre Seele verkauft haben

Comment: what exactly do you not understand??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the German equivalent (usually including the same dismissive intonation) of:

> "Just look at them,..."

I suppose you have trouble with the "doch" in the German sentence, right? 
In this case, it serves precisely the same function as the English "just": intensifying and giving a negative tone to the statement.

Also, note elena's comment below about "schau dir X an" being the equivalent of "look at X".

Comment: Another difficulty might be the fact that "sich anschauen" is reflexive and requires a dative reflexive pronoun. "Schau", "dir" and "an" are all parts of "look at".

Comment: Plus, there is a non-reflexive variant of _anschauen_, too (with a slight shift in meaning).

Comment: also note that the beautiful *doch* can only be used here as part of a dialogue or maybe monologue, i.e. the speaker must be talking to somebody.

Comment: @RalfH.: that is not because of doch but because it is a second person singular imperative...of course you need to talk to someone, if you give an order. Doch has nothing to do with that and there are sentences with doch that work just fine without a direct dialog

Comment: ja sicher, Du kannst schreiben: "er hatte seinen Hut doch nicht gefunden", aber das ist ein anderes *doch*. Dieses Verstärkungs-Doch geht nur, wenn man jemanden anspricht.

Comment: Sind Sprachsituationen ohne Adressaten nicht ohnehin rar? Ich kann doch immer „ich kann doch immer schreiben“ schreiben.

Comment: Wenn ich als Erzähler in der dritten Person für kurze Zeit indirekt die Gedankengänge meines Protagonisten nachvollziehe, dann ist das Fließtext, ohne direkte Rede und ohne Monolog. Beispiel: "Michael wunderte sich über Gabi's ablehnenden Gestus, hatte sie doch am Vorabend noch ganz andere Signale gesendet. Er blickte zum Heu in der Ecke..." ... wenn das als Monolog gilt, dann ist jedes Buch ein Monolog.